# Joomla Tooltip in Custom Component

Tags: joomla, tooltip, joomla1.5

I am creating a custom MVC component in Joomla and want to use tooltip to provide more information for specific field. I found this [tutorial on Joomla docs website showing how to use tooltip](http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial%3aHow_to_add_tooltips_to_your_Joomla!_website).

I followed the tutorial as close as possible but after page loads my tooltip is not display properly.

I see My `Title::My Description... blah blah blah`

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I do not even know where to look for the problem. I am a beginner with MVC, it is very confusing for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is title of span around the tooltip image, in format `Title::Description`

This can happen if:

1. You have an error in your JavaScript that prevents tooltip from initializing. [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) will help you to find JavaScript errors.
2. You did not include tooltip behavior. Make sure you added `JHTML::_('behavior.tooltip');` to `function display($tpl = null)` method of your view.

Comment: FireBug is awesome. In fact I did have js bug and my tooltip behavior was in controller... moved it to `dispaly` function, works like a charm. Thank you